Who sets trans student policy in English schools?
I am trying to mobilise parents to ensure their children's schools are following best practice on trans students, which is the Brighton and Hove toolkit: https://www.brighton-hove.gov.uk/node/776/trans-inclusion-schools-toolkit-2021
The Tories created a load of confusion on the way out and Labour don't seem keen to wade in, so I think the best way to impact this is on a local level. Should parents be talking to the head teacher or to the council or who?
Thanks

Hi les - while I think what you are doing is commendable, I do not think this is the best place for this question, as you are likely to get multiple different answers. Stack Exchange works well for specific questions with specific answers, not ones with multiple possible answers or opinions.

I think this is specific: the question is who sets policy, and hence who the OP should talk to about that policy to try to influence it.
That said, if nobody here knows then maybe Politics.SE would be better.

Paul, I don't think there is a specific answer though. I think it may vary by school, or local council, or region, based on what I could quickly find

I've been out of England for a while but I'm pretty sure it will indeed vary by council and/or school. @Ies_h, the version of the B&H Toolkit you linked is from 2021, do you know if a more recent version is available? There was a draft earlier this year but I don't know if it was published. AIUI the 2021 version is not up to date with current legislation so is unlikely to be recommended centrally.

Formally, this may be more a question for the law se site, in the sense of who has the power to such policies. In practice I would expect that the principal of the school would be the most productive person to talk to if you want to generate general awareness. If the schools need to invest money, you probably have to go higher up the food chain.
